# Use while loop to update multiple rows SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, while-loop, sql-update

I downloaded a database with over 90,000 rows. I need to make an edit to coulomb 2 of all rows by adding _id at the end of the value. I've never used SQL before so I'm not sure if its possible to just go through and add characters to the ends this way. what i have is this:

```
 SET @i = 01001
 WHILE(@i<93600)
  BEGIN 

        UPDATE NutritionTable
    SET field2 = (field2)"_id"
    WHERE field1=@i

SET @i = @i+1
  END -- WHILE
```

`field2` being the `coulomb` that needs to be updated, and `@id` is the row number. I'm getting near "SET":syntax error.

I've searched around for answers but haven't found much in regards to this. Any assistance would be appreciated, and apologies in advance if there is another post for this that I missed... or its some basics I'm missing.

Comment: You should be able to do this with one query. no need to loop through like this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop - you can just update all the rows, without a `where` clause:

```
UPDATE NutritionTable
SET    field2 = CONCAT(field2, '_id');
```